# PHP Rapid Deployment

Tags: php, deployment, web-deployment

Is there a good, simple solution for PHP "one-click" deployment to a production server? And also with a functionality to reverse back if needed.

In particular, I am interested in this with regards the PHP code itself. But if you know a good solution for MySQL, it is also welcome.

Comment: Are you asking for this solution to be written in PHP? Or something that can deploy your PHP code with one click?

Answer (score 0):

For deploying easily, we use Capistrano (its a Ruby tool, but deploys anything really) and its great, just need

```
cap deploy
```

from the command line (at its simplest)

If you want something written in PHP I can't name any I'm afraid.

For MySQL, I guess you would need some kind of migration tool, or build your db changes into SQL files that can be run by your deployment script.